# Can Java ParquetIO write empty parquet files ? And how?

Tags: apache-beam, parquet

I have a Java application which using Apache beam 2.20.  I read input files and do filtering and transforms and then write the result  to S3 with parquet format.

It was running quite well. But now encounter one issue is that, when I got some specific input files, After filtering, the result set PCollection might be empty. So if I write this empty PCollection to S3, the ParquetIO can completed, but there is no files in the target path.

I tried with TextIO to write empty PCollection. It can write successfully and the file is with 0 bytes.

So any solution can help to save an empty parquet file in beam?

As far as I know, in spark it can achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

The way the Beam model works, if an input PCollection to a transform is empty, that transform should never be executing. I'm a bit surprised to hear that TextIO is working that way, but it may be a convenient side effect of its setup, since real-world implementations often diverge a bit from the intended model.

But for ParquetIO, it's likely that creating no files is the intended behavior for empty PCollections. You would need to find some workaround to detect when filtering would result in an empty PCollection, and then trigger a custom transform to create an empty file some other way. Unfortunately I don't know enough to offer more detail on that approach.

Comment: thanks Daniel for the explanation.  I can confirm in my code TextIO does this way, as my application writes 2 formats now, csv and parquet. As per your explanation, I understand more abouts beam model.  But that results in an unpredictable result in the business use cases. It doesn't guarantee an file can be put there. So the next jobs which dependent on this path need to handle more scenarios.